# Why there is no remotes/origin/HEAD --> origin/master for a new branch which I pushed to repo

Tags: git, github, git-p4

I created a git branch and pushed it to origin master. Now when I do `git branch --all` it does not show me `remotes/origin/HEAD --> origin/master`.  I am able to perform all the git operations though.

- Is this expected?
- What is the logic behind having/not having this
  entry?

> **Edit:**

Looks like there is some confusion in what I actually did. I imported a repo from p4
Here is the sequence:

```
 1. git init 
 2. ../git/git-p4.py clone --detect-branches //projects/<my_project_path_in_p4>
 3. git checkout -q -b master refs/remotes/p4/<my_project_path>
 4. git add --all
 5. git commit -m "Initial Commit"
 6. git remote add origin <my_git_path>
 7. git push origin master
```

and then when i do git branch --all i don't see that particular entry:

```
* master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/p4/workflow_manager/workflow_manager-15.3.0
```

> ** Second Edit:**

When I clone the same branch and do `git branch --all` I get `remotes/origin/HEAD --> origin/master`. Here is the output after cloning which is expected

```
* master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
```

So now I am even more confused :)

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `git branch --all`. Also, you write: *I created a git branch and pushed it to origin master*. There seems to be some confusion, here: `git push origin master` means "Git, please push my local branch called 'master' to the remote repository that this local repo knows under the name 'origin'."

Comment: @Jubobs  added more details

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing in line (2) with `../git/git-p4.py clone --detect-branches //projects/<my_project_path_in_p4>`. What is the git command here?

Comment: Hi @Shaun this command is for checking out p4 branches using git-p4 plugin.

Comment: @AbhijitMazumder Aha. I have no idea how git-p4 works.

Answer (score 4):

## Why is `remotes/origin/HEAD` missing?

You could have deleted it from your machine via `git remote set-head -d origin`. It sounds like you didn't do that.

## How do I get it back?

In any case, you can get it back by running `git remote set-head -a`. This asks the remote to determine its `HEAD` and then updates your local appropriately.

## Is a missing remote `HEAD` expected?

No, that's not expected.

## Why would we have `remotes/origin/HEAD`?

`remotes\origin\HEAD` indicates the *default branch* on the remote. The logic is that you can then use `origin` as a shorthand whenever you would otherwise use `origin/master`. E.g. it makes `git log origin/master` equivalent to `git log origin`.

## See Also

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make git-p4 detect branches:

1. Have branch specifications defined in your P4 server that allow git-p4 to determine possible repartitions in the directory structure.
2. Use `git config --local git-p4.branchList path/to/branchA:path/to/branchB` to have the branch definitions local to your git repository.

Getting the second option right is sometimes difficult, but following your example I think that you should start by adding the following configuration:

```
git config --local git-p4.branchList workflow_manager/workflow_manager-15.3.0:workflow_manager/workflow_manager-15.3.0
```

Please note that in my personal experience I've always started by importing a P4 repository that already contained branches. That is, all the initialization work was done directly under P4. I suggest that you do the same. But take into consideration that for the branches to be correctly detected you need to import the complete history using the `@all` notation at the end of the P4 repository path.

An alternative would be to use a temporary git repository without branch detection for the initialization of the P4 server, then use P4 to integrate/copy/branch from the initial branch to the new one. At this point you should be able to correctly import the P4 repository to a new git repository using branch detection and the configurations I described above.